# Screen.Fonts без использования формы (в своем компоненте)

Tags: delphi

Не могу сделать компонент ComboFont на основе ComboBox, внутри лежат название шрифтов, установленных на компьютере

```
unit QCmbBx1;

interface

uses
SysUtils, Classes, QControls, QStdCtrls;

type
TComboBox1 = class(TComboBox)
private
  FComboBox1: TComboBox1 ;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TComboBox1]);
end;

constructor TComboBox1.Create(Aowner:Tcomponent );
begin
  inherited create(Aowner);
  FComboBox1.Items.Assign(Screen.Font s);
end;

end.
```

Пытаюсь понять, что с ними не так

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
   FCombobox:=TComboboxEx.Create(Self);
   FCombobox.Parent:=Self;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FCombobox.Destroy;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: А что с ним должно быть так, и что именно вам не нравится?

Comment: Он не работает, выдает ошибку, что идентификатор не объявлен , не понимаю, что сделать

Comment: Нужно выяснить (например, с помощью хелпа) , в каком модуле объявлен этот идентификатор, и включить его в uses

Comment: Если я использую Combobox как родителя, то он автоматически не должен быть там? я про screen.font

Comment: С чего бы это? Как связан Combobox и screen?  QControls, QStdCtrls, кстати, у вас откуда - свои модули или тяжкое наследие Delphi 6?

Comment: При создании своего компонента я выбрал TcomboBox  [QStdCtrls], вот поэтому и свое, TForm для screen нужно подключить в uses

Comment: Какая версия Delphi?

Comment: delphi 7, посмотрим , что будет, если я буду использовать StdCtrls

Comment: Ясно. Qxxx  - были в то время сделаны для кроссплатформенности (Linux) на основе QT, так что уберите такие модули.

Comment: Изменил , все осталось тем же , я не знаю , что делать, может вы попробуете сделать и скажете , что у меня не так?

Comment: Переменная screen объявлена в Forms, так что этот модуль нужно подключить.  Других вариантов при использовании Screen нет. Правда, ничего не мешает и самому получить список доступных шрифтов с помощью EnumFontFamiliesEx

Comment: сказали через screen.fonf делать